# Does the "site:" keyword and other "Advanced Search Options" apply to Bing Custom Search API?

Tags: bing, bing-api

We are using Bing Custom Search, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-custom-search/reference/endpoints, and passing a site: filter along with the search.  The current filter goes something like this:

```
https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/custom/search?q=searchTerm site:(support.somesite.com/en-us/productName)-(/productName/2/ OR /productName/3/)
```

My understanding is this will return results for "searchTerm" in the site `support.somesite.com/en-us/productName` and exclude sites (urls) containing `/productName/2/` or `/productName/3/`.

The idea is we have a search filter where customers can select specific versions of our product support documentation to search.  Selecting the filter excludes other versions of product from search results (i.e. versions `/productName/2/` and `/productName/3/` are excluded from search results).

However, in practice we are getting search results that contain urls with the versions we hope to exclude.

What is unclear from the documentation - do these https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/advanced-search-options-b92e25f1-0085-4271-bdf9-14aaea720930 **"advanced search options"** work with the site: keyword as we are attempting to use them above?  Or do they only work with the search query?

**Is there a good way to exclude particular url paths from the search?**

Comment: I am pretty sure it works with the aforementioned keyword. If you check this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/advanced-search-keywords-ea595928-5d63-4a0b-9c6b-0b769865e78a, 'site' keyword is also there.
In my view, you may need to add a NOT condition and add the webpages that you want to hide.
Also, you might need to address your request to: site:support.somesite.com/en-us/ (/productName/2/ OR /productName/3/ )

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69515253/19330634) help you ?

Comment: @laurentiurad the "-" is the same as NOT in this portion of the site: filter above "-(/productName/2/ OR /productName/3/)"  according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/advanced-search-options-b92e25f1-0085-4271-bdf9-14aaea720930

Comment: @l-_-l Thanks, unfortunately, Bing Web Search API is different than Bing Custom Web Search API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Bing Custom Web Search API does not fully support [Advanced Search Operators (keywords)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/advanced-search-keywords-ea595928-5d63-4a0b-9c6b-0b769865e78a), which includes the "site:" keyword.

MS Support pointed out that there is a difference between what is supported in the q= parameter between Bing Web Search API v7 (**not** used in this question) and Bing Custom Web Search API v7 (used in this question).

[image: Web Search vs Custom Search q= parameter]

[Web Search API v7 documentation (left in image)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-web-search/reference/query-parameters)

[Custom Web Search API v7 documentation (right in image)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-custom-search/reference/query-parameters)